# Creating Github repository for my Octopress source

Tags: github, octopress

I have an Octopress blog, having installed Octopress in the usual manner. I want to create a Github repository for my blog's source directory (and a few other files) only. I created a repository and did a "git init" in my Octopress directory. I added and committed files from the source directory.

I then did a "git remote add source https://github.com/howardm/[repository name].git"

Of course, I then screwed up doing a git push because I didn't realize "origin" and "master" already existed.

So, I 
1. deleted the repo 
2. removed the line concerning the "source" from `.git/config` in my Octopress directory.

(Should I delete the file itself and start over ?)

Now, I have:

```
howardm$ git remote -v

origin  git://github.com/imathis/octopress.git (fetch)
origin  git://github.com/imathis/octopress.git (push)
```

How should I create a new repo and properly push files to it to accomplish what I described above ?

Thanks!

Howard

Answer (score 0):

Follow those simple steps to create your blog:

```
# First clone the octopus or work on your local copy

# Install required packages etc
gem install bundler
bundler install

# Installl the Blog
rake install

# This is teh main part which you need to do.
# Delete the current github repository and create a new one
# Now use the octopress wizard to generate your blog and to deploy it yo github
rake setup_github_pages

# now generate the content  
rake generte

# And here comes the magic: Deploy to github
rake deploy
```

Thats it and now you have a full blog on github.